# htaccess redirect without .php extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I recently changed a directory `/old_dir/` to be `/new_dir/` using this:

`RedirectMatch 301 /old_dir/(.*) /new_dir/$1`

Which seems to be working perfect for the url:

`http://www.mysite.com/old_dir/test.php?var=xxxx`

goes to

`http://www.mysite.com/new_dir/test.php?var=xxxx`

where `test.php` is the filename. But in many places I use:

`http://www.mysite.com/old_dir/test?var=xxxx`

which comes up with:

`The requested URL /old_dir/test was not found on this server.`

not using the .php extension takes advantage of some sort of apache plugin that knows it's a php handler, which seemingly messes up redirect because it says it doesn't exist now.

I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Edit: All the solutions are for this special case, but note that i have about 1000 other files that may not be php, or named the same.

For right now I just made a symbolic link in the old_dir with the name "test" to point to the new_dir's test.php. But I am still looking for a non-specific solution that includes my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried using mod_rewrite?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1/$2.php [QSA] 
RewriteRule ^old_dir/([^/]+)/$ new_dir/$1.php [QSA]
```